# chnage image of button in swift everytime the user clicks on it

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I have a button in a tableview cell. I want that initially the button has an image "A", when the user clicks on it, it changes to "B", when the user clicks on it again it changes back to "A".

Let the two images to be "A" and "B" in this scenario

Comment: Did you already subclass your cell?

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk no. why would  i need to subclass it ?

Comment: That would be best if your going to include several methods and properties of the cell. So things don't get complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever the button is:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "a.png")!, forState: .Normal)
button.tag = 999

func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
     if sender.tag == 999 {
          sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "b.png")!, forState: .Normal)
          sender.tag = 0
     } else {
          sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "a.png")!, forState: .Normal)
          sender.tag = 999
     }
}
```

Comment: your solution works fine. I am scheduling a UIlocalNotification in the if block provided by you in your solution, but i am unable to cancel that localNotification in the else block(when the user taps the button again).
i am using UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(localNotification)

Answer (score 0):

You can add tag to the button.

```
// This code comes in viewDidLoad
button.tag = 1  // for A
button.titleLabel.text = "A"
```

// On-click of the button, check the tag and change the name

```
if button.tag == 1
{
   button.tag = 2
   button.titleLabel.text = "B"
}
```

Comment: He asked to set the image, but still that is the wrong way to set the title of a UIButton and that will get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIButton, add click handler in this class and make reference in Interface Builder. Then, create boolean property in your class, which you will trigger in click handler every time. In didSet of this property set proper image

Answer (score 0):

If we are just dealing with two states then this solution is easier and less messy. You can simply use UIButton states.

You can assign different images for default state and selected state in storyboard itself.

```
func pressed(sender:UIButton){
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
}
```

This will just change the states and images will be displayed depending on state.